# TIme different counting group by id in R Programming

Tags: r, time

Currently i tried:

```
bb <- numeric(100)

for(i in 2:10){bb[i]<-try$start_HHMM[i]-try$end_HHMM[i-1]} // i want to use the 2nd start time to - 1st end time to get the interval timing.
```

From the script that I tried above , I can get the interval timing but it is not the same id.

How can I put the condition in the script above to check the id?

[image]

Comment: The excessive use of pronouns gets in the way of communication . What does "it" refer to? And please do post an example using dput() and _not_ a picture!

Comment: The result given is 1620 - 1730 but they should with the same id. In this case, they take C Start Time - A End Time, it should be taken the row 3 A Start Time - row 1 A End Time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly (which is not a given, given the clarity of your question), you need to `split` your data.frame based on your ID first and then apply your loop on each sub-dataframes.

```
try_by_ID <- split(try,try$ID)

bb <- list()
for(i in seq_along(try_by_ID)){
    bb[[i]] <- c()
    for(j in 2:nrow(try_by_ID[[i]])){
        bb[[i]][j]<-try_by_ID[[i]]$start_HHMM[j]-try_by_ID[[i]]$end_HHMM[j-1]
        }
    }
names(bb) <- names(try_by_ID)
```

That's not a very pretty code snippet but since what you're trying to do is not very clear I can't propose anything nicer.